# Foreach loop could not get all the data i need to set privileges

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, privileges

I'm struggling to write privileges over LDAP login. I've tried to search here but no luck so far and I'm asking questions to You wise mentors.

I've created 9 groups users could be in multiple groups and i think of making an array and then on each page receiving if an array has an id of a group to let him in.

Each time when i print_r($_SESSION['access']) i've got one element from Array [0]
= > 2 ( with is correct because user is in group ,2 ,3, 4  ) but i dont get rest of array :(

Any suggestions ? or ideas on how to approach the topic in a different way?

````
    if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user.$ldap_usr_dom, $password)) {
        // valid
        // check presence in groups
        $filter = "(sAMAccountName=".$user.")";
        $attr = array("memberof");
        $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        ldap_unbind($ldap);

        // check groups
        $access = array();
        foreach($entries[0]['memberof'] as $grps) {
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_2_group)) { array_push($access, 2) ; }
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_3_group)) { array_push($access, 3) ; }
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_4_group)) { array_push($access, 4) ; }
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_5_group)) { array_push($access, 5) ; }
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_6_group)) { array_push($access, 6) ; }
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_7_group)) { array_push($access, 7) ; }
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_8_group)) { array_push($access, 8) ; }
            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_9_group)) { array_push($access, 9) ; }

            if(strpos($grps, $ldap_1_group)) { array_push($access, 1) ; }
        }

        if(empty($access)) {
            // user has no rights
            return false;           
        } else {
            // establish session variables
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['access'] = $access;
            return true;
        }

    }```
````

Comment: What does `var_dump($entries);` give (you can limit it to just the relevant content).

Comment: But how to store this in array in $_SESSION ? rest for me is easy.